# How to do SQL like queries with Active Record (count, group, order)

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm learning AR and attempting to build an Excel like table via a query to my database. I would appreciate any help in finding an efficient query for my conundrum.

My assumptions: I have determined the correct SQL query but am having problems translating it into a query that AR understands and that I can iterate through easily in my views.

My attempt: To create a table with a count of my user Action objects by state and month sorted in descending order like below:

## Wanted final output in View:

```
<table>
User_State   Jul-13   Aug-13 Sept-13 Total
FL           10       5      5       20
NY           5        5      5       15
</table>
```

## My example objects (input):

```
#<Action id: 1, user_state: "FL", month_part: 2013-07-01, first_name: "John">
#<Action id: 2, user_state: "FL", month_part: 2013-07-01, first_name: "Mike">
#<Action id: 3, user_state: "NY", month_part: 2013-07-01, first_name: "Jim">
```

## What I tried:

```
SELECT user_state, month_part, count(*) AS month_part_total
FROM actions
WHERE user_state IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT (user_state)
    FROM actions)
GROUP BY user_state, month_part
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is equivalent to following:-

```
SELECT user_state, month_part, count(*) AS month_part_total
FROM actions
GROUP BY user_state, month_part
```

as in `where` clause you are checking `user_state` in from the same table.

For this query, following should work:

```
Action.select("user_state, month_part, count(*)").group(:user_state, :month_part)
```